# Get multiple cursors (carets) at each find result in Intellij Idea editors?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to select all the string resource keys that contain the word "key" at the same time. I had a hard time figuring this out so I figured I'd post this for others. The [multicursor documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/multicursor.html) doesn't address this question.

An excerpt of the file I wanted to select from.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- User Preferences -->    
    <string name="preference_key_pedigree_enable_offline_mode">Pref.OfflineMode</string>
    <string name="preference_title_pedigree_enable_offline_mode">Offline Mode</string>
    <string name="preference_summary_on_pedigree_enable_offline_mode">Scans work without an internet connection, don\'t require a VIN and can\'t be saved.</string>
    <string name="preference_summary_off_pedigree_enable_offline_mode">Scan results will be sent to the server.</string>
    <string name="preference_default_pedigree_enable_offline_mode">false</string>

    <string name="preference_key_pedigree_hide_cleared_dtcs">pref_pedigree_hide_cleared_dtcs</string>
    <string name="preference_title_pedigree_hide_cleared_dtcs">Hide Cleared DTCs</string>
    <string name="preference_summary_on_pedigree_hide_cleared_dtcs">DTC\'s are hidden after they\'ve been cleared</string>
    <string name="preference_summary_off_pedigree_hide_cleared_dtcs">DTC\'s are still shown after they\'ve been cleared</string>
    <string name="preference_default_pedigree_hide_cleared_dtcs">true</string>

    <string name="preference_key_analytics_global_opt_out">pref_analytics_global_opt_out</string>
    <string name="preference_title_analytics_global_opt_out">Analytics Opt-Out</string>
    <string name="preference_summary_on_analytics_global_opt_out">Analytics switched off.</string>
    <string name="preference_summary_off_analytics_global_opt_out">Crash reports and usage statistics are being used to improve this app.</string>
    <string name="preference_default_analytics_global_opt_out">false</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for asking question it's very helpful for me.+1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Intellij Idea calls this [*multiselection*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d1743632e270).

Select the term to search for with your cursor. In my example, the word *key*
[image]
Next, *select all occurrences*:

- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- alternatively use the [find action menu](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-to-action.html?search=ctrl%20shift%20a) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> [image: action search screenshot]

[image: screenshot of selection]

Now you can expand your selection (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to the entire keys, and then copy and past elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

**Android Studio : Default Keyboard**

-> : Column selection mode = **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>** (Selection with Multi Cursor enable|Disable) 
-> : Find and select all occurrences with cursor = **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>**

-> : Multi cursor(Any line) = **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Click</kbd>** and **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Hold Mouse click</kbd>**

-> : Select Entire Word = **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>**

**Android Studio : eclipse Keyboard**

To search terms with multi cursor.
Just set eclipse keyboard in Android studio. 
Just Select terms and use shortcut like below.
PRESS :     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>